# Load COLLADA - geometry, animation, textures - what applies?

Tags: 3d, collada

I've been recommended to load 3D animations in the COLLADA format - I consulted the quick reference and docs for a while but I am pretty lost. What parts of the format do I actually care about if I want to:

- Load all vertices
- Load up all triangles or trianglestrips in the objects (relationships between verts)
- load animation info of where verts move to over time
- Textures and texcoord info

Also is there a file format I can convert COLLADA to that will more concisely and conveniently describe just that data? Or is it easier to pull from COLLADA format than I may think...

Comment: why reinvent the wheel? we also started writing our importer ourselves first, but we kept on adding and adding more parts of collada as we needed them until we came across people who had already dealt with the problem http://assimp.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty much doing the same thing at the moment. The most useful info I found describing whats going on in the COLLADA doc is here http://www.wazim.com/Collada_Tutorial_1.htm

For the mesh your mainly interested in the 'float_array' tags and if triangulated the 'p' tags unfortunately I only just started on the animation part myself so not much I can say there. But if you look into the file you'll see the layout is obvious in some parts i.e. 'library_animations' is where all the animation data is stored, 'library_geometries' for the mesh etc..

Answer (score 0):

What language is your game engine in? You could look at the easy-to-understand [jMonkeyEngine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/) or [Ardor3D](http://ardor3d.com/) sources, both of which support COLLADA loading. You can trace the geometry creation directly.

Comment: C/C++ but the language part isn't the trick part so I will consult those